# Inject .Class files into an existing Jar file

Tags: java, jar, bytecode

I am trying to solve a problem that `gradle` is limiting me on which is to run `compile` task once again. That is just not possible as the gradle `api` doesn't allow task re-invocation in the same gradle instance.

So I thought maybe if i just write a task that inject  the missing classes into that jar during the build (copy paste)

Is there any known way to inject a `.class` file into an existing `jar` file?

Comment: Jar files are just zipfiles. You can add files the same way you add files to any zip archive.

Comment: is there any extra indexing or mapping ? classpath whatsoever

Comment: There can be an optional [index entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Index_File_Specification) in the jar file.